# Garage airflow ideas

Tags: garage, exhaust-fan, cooling

I know this has been asked a multitude of times before, but I feel like I have a more unique scenario that wasn't directly addressed.

I have a 2 story home in SoCal. Garage temps aren't unbearable, but the air is completely stagnant. We also have a home gym in there and a solar inverter that gets hotter than I'm comfortable with (on days like today).

First thing I looked at was a small attic fan, like [this](https://www.coolmygarage.com/shop/gf-14-garage-fan-attic-cooler/), but there's a room above that covers about 3/4 of the garage. I also noticed that whatever space is above the garage does not have any exterior vents (soffit/gable/eave) - and as far as I can tell, the attic space directly above has zero airflow.

There are 2 gable vents on the side of the garage (one up high and one down low), right next to the inverter, so I also considered something like [this](https://www.coolmygarage.com/shop/gft-18-through-wall-garage-fan/).

What would be the best way to circulate air in here?

Comment: What color is the roof?  How do you feel about white?

Comment: At this level of detail? "Fix the attic ventilation" or "blow in one wall and suck from the other" - vague questions can only be answered vaguely. I have no sense from your text description what the structural layout of your garage is. Perhaps "blow a hole from the 1/4 that's not covered by a room into the attic and install a cupola on the peak" is the answer. Can't tell from here.

Comment: How's the attic space insulated?

Comment: what material are the shingles?